# Django Jinja2 variables in CSS occur red highlights in VSCode

Tags: css, django, django-templates, jinja2

I'm using Visual Studio Code. And I liked it. But when I use jinja in css or javascript, VSC always highlited in red.
How can I fix it? It's sometimes annoying.

I'm using Better Jinja plugin.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use plugins - `Django Template` and `Django`.

And there will be no problems.